# Затруднение с рандомом в динамическом массивом

Tags: c, массивы, файлы, динамические-массивы

Написал функцию, которая необходима для реализации динамического двухмерного массива с рандомным значением элементов. Однако компиллятор возвращает меня на место: error C2109: для индекса требуется массив или указатель (в строках, где тело вложенного цикла с rand(). Помогите, пожалуйста, с этой небольшой..как я думаю, проблемой.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int *get_matrix_rand(int size, int size2)
{
    int i, j;
    int* a = (int*)malloc(size * size2 * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)  // цикл по строкам
    {
        for (j = 0; j < size2; j++)  // цикл по столбцам
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("a[%i][%j] = %d ", i, j, a[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int **get_matrix_rand(int size, int size2)
{
    int** a = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = malloc(size2*sizeof(int));
        for(int j = 0; j<size2; j++)  // ???? ?? ????????
        {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100;
            printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Только еще: если у вас С - то о каком

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
```

вы говорите?! И - в С (подчеркиваю: в С, не С++) вот это приведение `int*`

```
(int*)malloc
```

не требуется.

И - потом не забудьте освободить память в обратном порядке. Сначала все `a[i]`, потом `a`.

Comment: Но тогда возникает проблема. "инициализация: невозможно преобразовать 'void *' в 'int **'" в строке  int** a = malloc(size*sizeof(int*));

Comment: Потому что вы компилируете программу как С++, а не как С! Файл должен иметь расширение .c, а не .cpp, или в настройках проекта должно быть указано, что это язык С.

Comment: Там вообще невообразимое месиво из Си и Си++.

Comment: Требования к модулям программы требовали подключения С++шной std для одной функции. Я уже понимаю, что подсунули такое...себе.. Но я не смогу вырезать это. Одновременно требуя и Си и С++, как мне привести все к общему знаменателю в этой ситуации? убрать malloc именно в этом случае?

Comment: Нет, можно оставить приведение. Но в С++ память выделяется через `new`, а вообще можно использовать `vector`. Зависит от того, что вы делаете и для чего...

Comment: То есть, если переписать код на с++ через new int - то моя сборная солянка будет функционировать?

Comment: Если переписать правильно - будет...